# Python Streamlit - Twitter API response to pandas stays empty

Tags: python, pandas, twitter, streamlit

I want to develop a dashboard by using the newest streamlit.io version. I am using Python 3.11.0.

I want to show up some prefiltered tweets that I request via Tweepy library from the Twitter API v2.

After receiving the data I want to clean up the data and put it into a table using pandas to import this data into my local InfluxDB database. That is the point where I am stuck right now and am hoping for help :)

```
#Build the query string
query = '(from:user1 -is:retweet -is:reply "#") OR from:user2 -is:retweet -is:reply "#"'
    
tweets = client.search_recent_tweets(query=query, 
                                     max_results=10,
                                     tweet_fields=['created_at', 'text'],
                                     user_fields = ["name", "username"],
                                     expansions = 'author_id')
st.write(tweets.text)
```

This code block works very well and tweets.text gives me every information about the tweets for the two twitter accounts I am queried for.

```
tweets = []
columns=['user','text','date']
for tweet in tweets:
    tweets.append({'date': tweet.created_at,
                   'user': tweet.user.screen_name,
                   'text': tweet.text,
                  })
dftweets = pd.DataFrame(tweets, columns=columns)

print(f"Number of tweets returned: {len(tweets)}")
```

In this part I am trying to exclude the necessary information by using pandas. But my check "print Number of tweets returned:" gives me the answer "0".

What am I missing here?

And one last further question regarding the Twitter API query. Right now the query contains only two different accounts but if the number of accounts will increase the query would be longer and longer. Is it possible to define the accounts somewhere (e.g. accounts=user1,user2,userN...) and use this in the query?

Thanks a lot guys any help is very appreciated!

Bart

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, concerning to your first question:

> What am I missing here?

The problem i can see is that you redefined the variable `tweets = []`, so maybe you are rewritting that variable with empty values. I would use prints inside the for loop

```
for tweet in tweets:
    print("Tweet TEST")
    print(tweet.text)
    tweets.append({'date': tweet.created_at,
                   'user': tweet.user.screen_name,
                   'text': tweet.text,
                  })
```

So you can check lively the tweets that are appearing, also a test solution is use a counter in the for and you can be sure how much time the loops works and you know how mucha tweets are inside the tweets variable.

But i don´t think that that´s your problem, it semes that your problem is that you are not using correctly the return value from the function `Client.search_recent_tweets()`, it´s type is `tweepy.Response(data, includes, errors, meta)` as you can check in the doc web: https://docs.tweepy.org/en/stable/client.html#tweepy.Client.search_recent_tweets

To loop around the values of tweets returned you have to use the argument `.data`

```
for tweet in tweets.data:
    print(tweet.text)
```

There is another ways to get the tweets using libraries `streamlit` and `tweepy`, using part of the code that is exposed to answer the next question.

> Is it possible to define the accounts somewhere (e.g. accounts=user1,user2,userN...) and use this in the query?

I know that using the library `streamlit` and `tweepy` is an option because you can loop all accounts and get all tweets from each account.

```
default_accounts = ['juan1',
'pepe2',
'link_por4',
'RickAll']
accounts = default_accounts + ['']

included_accounts = st.multiselect('Accounts', accounts, default_accounts)

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(api_key, api_secret_key)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)
for account in included_accounts:
    st.write(account)
    tweets = api.user_timeline(screen_name=account, count=200, tweet_mode='extended')
    for tweet in tweets:
        print(tweet.full_text)
```

the function `user_timeline` uses the account reference to get the tweets, but with `Client.search_recent_tweets()` function i can´t give an accurate answer